# connect through for OraOLEDB/connecting from one user to another using OraOLEDB/Connect from one user to another Oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, connection-string, ado, oraoledb

I had granted `connect through` privileges for one user to another using below code

`alter user user_a  grant connect through user_b;`

Then using sqlplus I was able to connect to `user_a` by using user_id and password for `user_b` using command below

`sqlplus user_b[user_a]/password_b@MyDatabase`

How can I do it using OraOLEDB

I had tried below but it gave user id string error

`connstring = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MyDatabase;User ID=user_b[user_a];Password=password_b;Data Provider=MSDASQL"`

Answer (score 1):

Hello

> ODP.NET applications can use proxy authentication by setting the
> "**Proxy User Id**" and "**Proxy Password**" attributes in the connection
> string. The real user is specified by the "User Id" attribute.
> Optionally, to enforce greater security, the real user's password can
> be provided through the "Password" connection string attribute. When
> using distributed transactions in conjunction with proxy
> authentication, the real user's password is no longer optional, and it
> must be supplied.

`connect through` should be configured in the OLEDB connection string using the aforementioned format:

```
Data Source=myOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Proxy User Id=pUserId;Proxy Password=pPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto It works with ```OracleConnection``` , there are many documentation (https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/ProxyUserConnection.html)  on that too using ```OracleConnection```, but with ```ADODB.Connection``` this proxy user id is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only option available with ADODB connection for EXCEL macro Visual basic is to run below alter statement

`alter session set CURRENT_SCHEMA=proxy_user`

but then grants need to be handled explicitly for the actual user, this is an disadvantage using this.